Is this affine morphism an isomorphism?
I am sorry if my question turns out to be too easy, but I've been struggling with it for a while now. I would appreciate any corrections or suggestions to improve the attempt below.
Let $f:X \to Y$ be a morphism of schemes, suppose that $f$ is affine, i.e. the preimage $f^{-1}(V)$ of every open affine $V$ in $Y$ is affine in $X$.
If the comorphism $f^\sharp  : \mathcal{O}_Y \to f_* \mathcal{O}_X$ is an isomorphism, can I conclude that $f$ is an isomorphism?
My attempt: Yes, $f$ is an isomorphism. For every open affine $V$ in $Y$:

the preimage $f^{-1}(V)$ is open and affine in $X$, and
we have an isomorphism (of rings?) $$f^\sharp (V): \mathcal{O}_Y(V) \to \mathcal{O}_X(f^{-1}(V)).$$
This implies that $f$ is locally an isomorphism, hence an isomorphism.


Yes, your proof is correct. The map f#(V) is indeed a ring isomorphism.

@BrianNugent that looks like an answer to me. Please consider recording it as such below. To the OP, please don't delete and repost your question. That's an inappropriate method of bumping it.

How does this argument show that $f$ is a homeomorphism? It feels to me like something is missing. I suppose it's true because one can show that $X \cong \underline{\operatorname{Spec}}_Y(\mathcal{O}_Y) \cong Y$.

@KReiser Sorry, I had no idea that reposting was inappropriate (as I do it on other platforms), what should I normally do instead?

I don't understand your argument. Locally isomorphism does not imply isomorphism (Etale morphisms exist). As the comment before says, for any affine morphism $ f : X \rightarrow Y $ we have $ X \cong \operatorname{Spec}Y( f* \mathcal{O}_X ) $ and this proves the statement.

I think that the OP means locally an isomorphism on the target, which is sufficient to be an isomorphism, but could clarify their phrasing.

Your proof is correct. You have shown that the map $f$ is an isomorphism locally on the target, which shows it is an isomorphism.
One thing to note is that the assumption that $f$ is affine is very necessary. It is very common to have morphisms where $f^\#: \mathcal{O}_Y \rightarrow f_*\mathcal{O}_X$ is an isomorphism. For example, this happens for any projective morphism with geometrically connected fibers.
